# Removing 'syncthing' from Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04 & I installed `syncthing`.  After exploring it a bit, it didn't fit my need (local backup to USB) so I've tried deleting it with no success.  I have a remnant somewhere that I can't seem to clean out. This is what I see in `apt`:

```
~$ apt list syncth*
Listing... Done
syncthing-discosrv/jammy 1.18.0~ds1-3 amd6
syncthing-gtk/jammy,jammy 0.9.4.4+ds+git20220108+9023143f8b93-1 all
syncthing-relaysrv/jammy 1.18.0~ds1-3 amd64
syncthing/jammy 1.18.0~ds1-3 amd64
```

These are the things I've tried:

```
sudo apt remove syncthing*
sudo apt auto clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then ran `sudo apt update` followed by `apt list syncht*` and... they're back!

Tried dpkg with `sudo dpkg --purge syncthing` with a result of:

```
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove syncthing which isn't installed
```

Installed Synaptic, found the four modules.  Marked them for install, applied, marked for `complete removal` and applied.  Ran `sudo apt update` and.... they're back!

'whereis syncthing' and 'which syncthing' don't find anything.

I removed the sources list: `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/syncthing.list`

Reran `sudo apt update` and `apt list syncth*` and... they're still there.

Tried this which didn't work either:

```
sudo apt install syncthing-discosrv syncthing-gtk syncthing-relaysrv syncthing

sudo apt purge  syncthing-discosrv syncthing-gtk syncthing-relaysrv syncthing
```

I am missing something (obviously).  Any thoughts on how to remove `syncthing-discosrv`, `syncthing-gtk`, `syncthing-relaysrv`, `syncthing` from showing up in `apt` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have successfully removed the packages from your system.

You missunderstand the output of `apt list`.`apt list` lists available packages wether they are installed or not. The packages exist in the repository, so they should be listed, it does not mean that the packages are installed in your system.

Removing the ppa doesn't make a change in the output of `apt list syncthing` since the packages are also available from original repos.

`apt policy` instead will show you if any of the packages are installed.

Here the example output from my system for the `syncthing`-package:

```
~$ apt list syncthing
Listing... Done
syncthing/jammy 1.18.0~ds1-3 amd64
~$ apt policy syncthing
syncthing:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.18.0~ds1-3
  Version table:
     1.18.0~ds1-3 500
        500 http://mirror1.totbb.net/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
```